# How do you use the "this" pointer in C++ in objects?

Tags: c++, class, compare, this

This is my class,

```
#ifndef CARD_H
#define CARD_H

class Card
{
    private:
            int suit, value;
    public:
            Card (int, int);
            int Compare (Card)const;
            void print_card()const;
};

#endif
```

For my compare function, I want to compare the values, and then suits, of two cards and then return 1 if the object card is greater and 0 if the card i'm comparing it to is greater. How do I accomplish this?

And my Card constructor is supposed to create a new card, but im not allowed to use "new" in the constructor statement. How am I supposed to create new cards if this is the case?

This is what i tried for compare:

```
int Card::Compare(Card c1) const
{

    if ( c1 == NULL && this == NULL ) return 0;
    else if ( c1 == NULL ) return -1;
    else if ( this == NULL ) return 1; 

    else if ( c1.value > this.value ) return 1;
    else if ( c1.value < this.value ) return -1;
    else if ( c1.value == this.value )
    {
        if ( c1.suit > this.suit ) return 1;
        if ( c1.suit < this.suit ) return -1;
    }
```

Comment: Seems to me like `Compare` should just be a regular `operator>` overload. I also don't see where you'd need to use `this`.

Comment: I added what i tried.

Comment: `c1 == NULL && this == NULL`. How do you envision either of these ever being `NULL`? You really need to start with a beginners [book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Answer (score 1):

In C++ the `this` **pointer** is a pointer to the present instance of the class.

Because it is a pointer you must treat it as a pointer:
`this->member` or `(*this).member`

In C++ you only need to use the `this` pointer to avoid naming conflicts with method parameters.

I have never used the `this` pointer because I refer to the members directly and purposely use different names between method parameters and member variables.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should read a basic C++ tutorial.
In short:

1) You don't need the `this` pointer, it is implicit and it is not a good practice to use it to access member in general (sometimes you don't have choice to disambiguate with a local variable):

```
bool Card::Compare(const Card &c1) const  // Note, usage of const reference
{ 
    // c1 is NOT a pointer, no need to check for NULL
    // checking this is not a usual idiom

    if ( c1.value > value ) return true;  // same as if ( c1.value > this->value ) return true;
    if ( c1.value < value ) return false; 
    if ( c1.suit > suit ) return true;
    if ( c1.suit < suit ) return false;
    return true;
}
```

2) The constructor is called when the client create a Card, it does not have to do anything.

```
Card *some_card = new Card(1, 2); // constructor is called with 1 and 2
```

Note that `new` is not required for automatic allocation:

```
Card some_card(1, 2); // constructor is called with 1 and 2
```

Now, multiple things could be improved in your code, like not using `int` as it is not type safe, and using operators > and < to compare card.

Comment: So then in the section of my code where I say: "if ( c1 == NULL && this == NULL ) return 0; " what would I replace "this" with?

Comment: Nothing. `c1` is not a pointer, so you CANNOT check it for NULL, and there is rarely ever a good reason to check `this` for NULL. Simply don't call `Compare()` on an invalid `Card` object to begin with, or bad thins happen.

Comment: @user3380850 you don't replace this with anything, you just don't do any test here.

Comment: @RemyLebeau c1 is a reference, you *can* compare its address with nullptr. Note I didn't say it is good practice :)

Comment: A reference cannot have a null value. Comparing `c1 == NULL` and `c1 == nullptr` are not allowed when `c1` is a reference. You can use `&c1 == NULL` and `&c1 == nullptr`, but those are useless comparisons.

Comment: @RemyLebeau a reference can have a null *value*, for instance if c1 is a reference to a pointer the comparison you mention are fine, but the semantic is not the same. Secondly I was talking about the address of the reference, or the address of the object referred to, i.e. `&c1`. You consider them "useless comparisons", I wouldn't say so but note that I wrote *no need to check for NULL* for the reference in the code. NULL reference should NOT happen in a correct program, just as bugs should not appear, however we are still using assert() during development/debugging...

Comment: @Joky: a reference cannot have a null value (unless you have corrupted memory). It must always point at something. A reference can point at a variable that itself has a null value, but that is a separate matter, and irrelevant to this discussion, since this code is copying values from one object instance to another, so there is no null object involved.

Comment: How is it different from anything I said?

Answer (score 0):

You usually use the "this" object when you want to use it outside of your class. If you are calling a function that is outside of your class and want to pass the current object to that function, you will pass in the "this" pointer. The function obviously has to take the same class (or a derrived class) where you want to call the function from.

Example:

```
void DoSomeThingElse(A *object) {};

class A
{
    void DoSomething()
    {
        DoSomethingElse(this);
    }
}
```